# python - string conversion

Tags: python

I know, the title to this question is vague, but I don't really know how else to describe it. Here's what I'm trying to do though.

I'm using `pyodbc` to query a database, and I want to allow the user to specify a column, and for my code to fetch it dynamically. In other words, I need to do something like this:

```
row_id = "row.%s" % id_column
```

Of course, this returns a string. What pyodbc is expecting is a variable/property, like so:

```
row_id = row.id
```

Could someone please tell me how to do this? I tried searching for "python string to val" but all those pages tell me how to convert a string to an int- which is different than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide a longer sample from your code? Also consider looking at: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
row_id = getattr(row, id_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
getattr(row,'id')
```

or maybe I don't really get what you want to do...